# PHP: combine two sets of code into one (to achieve displaying text file in a certain way)

Tags: php, sorting

I have 2 sets of code, which both work on their own, but I need to combine them both, and havent been able to do it.

The end result should be to display a text file, line by line, with array #, alphabetically (and therefore array numbers should display at the end of each line).

**FIRST PIECE OF CODE**

```
<?php
$filename="users.txt"; 
$lines = array();
$file = fopen($filename, "r");

while(!feof($file)) { 
    $lines[] = fgets($file,4096);
} 

natcasesort($lines);
$text = implode("<br />", $lines);
print_r($text);

fclose ($file); 
?>
```

**SECOND PIECE OF CODE**

```
<?php 
 $lines = file('users.txt'); 
 foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) 
{ 
 print "<font color=red>Line #{$line_num}</font> : " . $line . "<br />\n"; 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the variable names? -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two easy ways to do this. This one will only work for PHP >= 5.4.0:

```
$lines = file('users.txt');
asort($lines, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE); // natcasesort that preserves keys!

foreach ($lines as $num => $line) { 
    printf("%s (line #%d)<br>", $line, $num);
}
```

If using an earlier version, you can achieve the same effect with [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and [`strnatcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php):

```
$lines = file('users.txt');
uasort($lines, 'strnatcasecmp'); // natcasesort that preserves keys

// the loop is the same
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ShAvp7)**.

In both case the idea is to use a sort function that maintains index association, so that after the lines are sorted they remain indexed by their original key (which is the line number in the file). Both `usort` and `uasort` do this; `uasort` allows you to specify the sort comparison function yourself while `usort` only allows a few built-in options (which do not include natural sorting in PHP < 5.4).

As an aside: *please* do not use the `<font>` tag ever again.

Comment: I have an older version, so the 2nd one worked great. Is it possible to also change the line # colour to red as well. I dont know how to add this in <font color=red>Line #{$line_num}</font>I got that script from somewhere else, so should I be using style sheets to change font colour. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @KGreen: Something as simple as `<span style="color: red">xx</span>` will do it, but take a look at a CSS reference.